# Insert XML result from curl to database

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to insert the xml result from curl to database and I'm facing problems the data does not enter database. I have tried both mysqli method and PDO as well but the data does not enter database. Can anyone help me out with this.Here's my code:-

**MYSQLI**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?".$queryString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
// Save response to the variable $data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
// Close Curl connection
if ($data === False) {
    echo "cURL ERROR:".curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $url."?".$queryString;
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($data, true));
echo '</pre>';
$xml= simplexml_load_string($data);
//print_r($xml) ;
con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"test") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
foreach($xml -> Products as $product) {
   $product->Product;
   {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($product->name);
        $short_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($product-
                             >short_description);
        $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($product->brand);
        $model = mysqli_real_escape_string($product->model);
        $warranty_type =mysqli_real_escape_string($product->warranty_type);

         $sql = "Insert into test (name, short_description, 
                   brand,model,warranty_type ) " . "Values 
         ('$name','$short_description','$brand','$model','$warranty_type')";
          $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          error_log($sql);
          if (!$result) {
          echo 'Error:' . mysqli_error($con);
          } else {
           echo 'Success';
         }
     }
 }

**PDO**
$db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','root','');
$xmldoc= new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc -> load($data);

$xmldata = $xmldoc ->getElementsByTagName('Product');
$xmlcount = $xmldata ->length;

for($i=0; $i< $xmlcount; $i++){
$name = $xmldata -> item($i) ->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)-> 
childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue->item(0);
$short_description = $xmldata -> item($i) -
>getElementsByTagName('short_description')->item(0)-> childNodes->item(0)-
>nodeValue->item(0);
$brand = $xmldata -> item($i) ->getElementsByTagName('brand')->item(0)-> 
childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue->item(0);
$model = $xmldata -> item($i) ->getElementsByTagName('model')->item(0)-> 
childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue->item(0);
$warranty_type = $xmldata -> item($i) -
>getElementsByTagName('warranty_type')->item(0)-> childNodes->item(0)-
>nodeValue->item(0);
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into test values(?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt -> bindParam(1,$name);
$stmt -> bindParam(2,$short_description);
$stmt -> bindParam(3,$brand);
$stmt -> bindParam(4,$model);
$stmt -> bindParam(5,$warranty_type);
$stmt ->execute();

}
```

The PDO method shows that getElementsByTagName not found in DOMNode. I am using PHPStorm 2016.2.1 as my IDE.

---

This is the response I get from curl in xml format

```
<SuccessResponse>
  <Head>
   <RequestId>0a1530d415089888818591159e</RequestId>
   <RequestAction>GetProducts</RequestAction>
   <ResponseType>Product</ResponseType>
   <Timestamp>2017-10-26T03:34:40+0000</Timestamp>
   <isES>true</isES>
</Head>
 <Body>
   <TotalProducts>589</TotalProducts>
    <Products>
    <Product>
    <PrimaryCategory>10001164</PrimaryCategory>
    <SPUId/>
    <Attributes>
      <name>Big Rabbit Furry Key Chain (Light Blue)</name>
      <short_description>&lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="font-
   family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:10pt"&gt;A perfect gift for yourself 
  or someone special&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="font-
 family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:10pt"&gt;Good accessory for handbag, 
 tote backpack cellphones, keychain or car&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt; 
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="color:rgb(17, 17, 17); font-family:arial,sans-
 serif; font-size:10pt"&gt;Super cute and soft&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt; 
 &lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="color:rgb(17, 17, 17); font-family:arial,sans-
 serif; font-size:10pt"&gt;Ideal companion of your keys, bags, cellphones 
 car or other wonderful objects&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;span 
 style="color:black; font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-
 size:10pt"&gt;Size(cm): 10 x 6 x 18&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;
 </short_description>
      <video/>
      <services/>
      <brand>Not Specified</brand>
      <model>bulu15-lightblue</model>
      <color_family/>
      <Hazmat/>
      <warranty_type>No Warranty</warranty_type>
      <warranty/>
      <product_warranty/>
      <name_ms>Big Rabbit Furry Key Chain (Light Blue)</name_ms>
      <product_warranty_en/>
      <description_ms/>
      <external_url/>
    </Attributes>
    <Skus>
      <Sku>
        <Status>active</Status>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
        <tax_class>default</tax_class>
        <_compatible_variation_>...</_compatible_variation_>
        <SellerSku>test112</SellerSku>
        <ShopSku/>
        <package_content>&lt;p&gt;1 x Big Rabbit Furry Key Chain (Light Blue)&lt;/p&gt;</package_content>
        <Url/>
        <package_width>6.00</package_width>
        <package_height>18.00</package_height>
        <special_price>0.0</special_price>
        <price>0.0</price>
        <package_length>10.00</package_length>
        <package_weight>0.10</package_weight>
        <Available>100</Available>
        <Images>
          <Image>https://my-live.slatic.net/original/601531319cd1dca721c70637e96cc403.jpg</Image>
          <Image>https://my-live.slatic.net/original/7e6ad47bbfa1de474fe36c20b06c35f7.jpg</Image>
          <Image>https://my-live.slatic.net/original/02bc2102d6864a867c25328724f0c7c7.jpg</Image>
          <Image/>
          <Image/>
          <Image/>
          <Image/>
          <Image/>
        </Images>
      </Sku>
    </Skus>
  </Product>
```

Comment: Can you show what you are getting back from curl ($data)

Comment: https://api.sellercenter.lazada.com.my?Action=GetProducts&Format=XML&Timestamp=2017-10-26T03%3A34%3A40%2B0000&UserID=kuhaanand%40consultenvision.com&Version=1.0&Signature=f5725c773bd3f5fa3bedaf5277cb90af4af84e2f8671d50661da0a404752e609(This is the response url that i get from curl which is placed in $data)

Comment: That gives me XML with the error - E3:Timestamp has expired, can you add at least a partial copy of the data to your question.

Comment: I am getting the url from lazada api and it displays a list of products in xml format

Comment: So can you add some of that XML data to your question!

Comment: If you are getting data back from the URL, then the problem is just an XML parsing error. To help you with that we need to see the XML.

Comment: Do you really have `$xml -> Products`, with spaces in your code?  And `$product->short_description` with a newline in the middle?

Comment: I have added the ouput from curl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your PDO version of the code.

The first is that your using `$xmldoc -> load($data);`, `load()` is expecting a file name and your passing in the actual data.  So change this to `loadXML()`.

Then when your accessing the elements of the data, your using 
`->nodeValue->item(0)`.  `nodeValue` gives you the contents of the node, so you need to stop at this point.  In the code below, I've just changed it for the name, but you should see how this needs to be changed through your code.

```
$xmldoc= new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc -> loadXML($data);

$xmldata = $xmldoc ->getElementsByTagName('Product');
$xmlcount = $xmldata ->length;

for($i=0; $i< $xmlcount; $i++){
    $name = $xmldata -> item($i) ->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->
        childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

        echo $name;
}
```

Comment: Would be interested as to why this is downvoted.  Happy to learn from my mistakes, but not sure what they are as there is no feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the changes. I tried adding it to my code but I get this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function item() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\qijang\new.php:223 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\qijang\new.php on line 223

Comment: OK - can you show what line 223 is?  It's difficult to help without knowing what is causing the error.

Comment: actually on line 223 there is only a closed curly brace.

Comment: Have you changed each time you access the XML, where I say about not putting anything after the `->nodeValue` part?  I only showed an example, you need to do the rest!

Comment: I changed the first two and the rest I forgot thanks for reminding by the way. But now it doesn't display the error and the data doesn't enter database.

Comment: When you do an insert, it's always better to list the fields you are intending to insert into.  Also in the first example code, you check for errors after the `execute` - can you do the same with the PDO version and see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Nigel Ren now it's functioning without any problems. I think the problem was with fields as you said to type in the column names and now its working.